# Make mxgraph open an xml automatically

Tags: javascript, xml, mxgraph

I am trying to make this app open with an xml file (empty one if no file exists) and when I close it, it saves it automatically to that same location.

I have the source code and I have been trying to figure it out but without any luck. For example EditorUi.js, line 3029 is where it opens files, but doesn't help me much. It might be important to say I have never worked in such a project and I'm pretty much new to javascript programming.

Source Code: http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my anser for this question:
[Opening local files in MxGraph via urlParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064901/opening-local-files-in-mxgraph-via-urlparam)

If it doesn't guide you the way feel free to ask a more precise question!